# How to Autoscroll to bottom on listview?

Tags: android, xml

I have application with ListView. This ListView has a Progressbar.When I am clicking on this Progressbar, then it is showing a hided Layout(This layout contain textview with lyrics). So as I am clicking on the last Progressbar then it is showing the hided Layout, but I need to scroll manually. I want that scrolling must be automatically.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void scroll2bottom() {
    yourListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourListView.setSelection(yourListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No it's not working, I just call this method in onItemClick().

Comment: Confirm that you're actually entering that method, I've been using that code in several projects and it always has worked!

Answer (score 2):

You might find the `smoothScrollByOffset()` or `smoothScrollBy()` methods of `ListView` most useful. In particular `smoothScrollBy()` takes both a distance to scroll and a duration over which the scroll animation should take place. With this method you can control precisely how far to scroll the list.

Answer (score 1):

in your layout of your listview just use the transcriptMode

a listview has builtin auto scroll

android:transcriptMode="normal" witll scroll when its at the bottom but not when you have scrolled away

and the setting alwaysScroll will always scroll to the bottom

and then you can set the android:stackFromBottom="true" to make it grow from the bottom

Comment: It is taking by default Scroll in last end, but I want that initially scroll must be up side and when I click on the last progressbar then, the Hided Layout will come, but it is not appearing, because i need to do scroll manually. But I want that at this moment scroll must be automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL); 
lv.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

Comment: You should probably try and explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll a listView programmatically you can use its smoothScrollByOffset(int offset) or smoothScrollToPosition(int position) methods, you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) the documentation about the ListView widget and how to use those methods.